Type narrowing with enum and interface map as function parameter
Why in this code the narrowing doesn't work within the switch case in the function but it works when calling the function.
export enum Kind {
    A,
    B,
    C,
}

export interface KindMap {
    [Kind.A]: {
        a: string
    }
    [Kind.B]: {
        b: number
    }
    [Kind.C]: {
        c: string[]
    }
}

const func = <T extends Kind>(kind: T, info: KindMap[T]) => {
    switch (kind) {
        case Kind.A: {
            info.a // error, narrowing doesn't work here

            break
        }
    }
}

// Narrowing works correctly here
func(Kind.A, { a: 'string' })
func(Kind.B, { b: 1 })
func(Kind.C, { c: ['string'] })

Playground

Solved it, by restructuring the type. Instead of using 2 parameters, I used 1 parameter info and include the kind in it.
export enum Kind {
    A,
    B,
    C,
}

type Info =
    | {
            kind: Kind.A
            a: string
      }
    | {
            kind: Kind.B
            b: number
      }
    | {
            kind: Kind.C
            c: string[]
      }

const func = (info: Info) => {
    switch (info.kind) {
        case Kind.A: {
            info.a // error, narrowing doesn't work here

            break
        }
    }
}

// Narrowing works correctly here
func({ kind: Kind.A, a: 'string' })
func({ kind: Kind.B, b: 1 })
func({ kind: Kind.C, c: ['string'] })

Playground
